# Generate .exe from my web service

Tags: wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2010, exe

So I have created a Web Service the same way as every other one I normally create. Problem is, I want to run it to test if it starts correctly.

If I right click the project -> properties -> debug, you should be able to tell it to start an external .exe which always seemed to be in the /bin/debug folder of the solution for me, but this project is not generating one, so I can't actually start it.

Do you know if there's a setting where I can get it to generate an .exe?

Comment: There is nothing to "run" in a web service. There's nothing to start. What are you trying to do?

Comment: The way we test is to compile the web service, and then start it on our local machines by referencing the .exe file, and then we change the app config in our other solutions to point to our local machines.

Comment: A web service runs in the context of a web server. Not sure what exactly mean by an `exe` here?

Comment: @JohnSaunders is correct if your project is a WCF service then you don't have an exe and can't run it. You can start it from a console app or a windows Service or from IIS.

Comment: What kind of web service do you have that you can compile and then "reference the .exe file"? Can you show how you do that? Because I've never heard of that with .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test a WCF you can use the WCF Test Client

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\WcfTestClient.exe

You then start debugging (f5) your WCF application and add the service URL to the test client

If you are using a webservice then you can start debugging (f5) and since it is local you can pass non complex parameters to test the methods, otherwise you would need to create a new project to test the service.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best approach would be to create a console app which starts your service this will be your server and you could make a console app as a test client or use some Test framework for testing your service like 
NUnit
MS-Test